# Sound doesn't work in x, but does in virtual terminal

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I've just installed Fedora 19, bringing over my home directory. I've disabled graphical boot, instead I get dumped to a virtual terminal. I use xmonad instead of gnome3.

## weird phenomenon #1

In a virtual terminal, I can run `alsamixer -c0` as my normal user without problem.

When I launch X (`startx -- vt3`), I open a terminal, run `alsamixer -c0`, and it doesn't work, saying:

```
% alsamixer -c0
invalid card index: 0
try `alsamixer --help' for more information
```

So now I'm in an Xsession, as my normal user, and alsamixer is borked. If I run `sudo alsamixer -c0`, it works. Also, I can switch back to a virtual terminal and run it as my normal user.

Pulse is installed and running. I can hear audio played from the virtual terminal. I've tried starting x, killing pulse, and manually starting pulse, but I still only see pulse's dummy device.

`aplay -l` in a virtual terminal:

```
19:06:28 jake@localhost]~% aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay -l` in an xsession:

```
19:06:51 jake@localhost]~% aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

## weird phenomenon #2

If I start playing some music in the virtual terminal, and switch over to an x session, `mplayer` pauses. Like, I hear music, note the play position, switch to x session, the music stops, I wait ten seconds, switch back to the vt, the music starts, play position is where it was when I switched to X.

## permissions of `/dev/snd/*`

```
% ls -l /dev/snd*
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       80 Jul  9 13:00 by-path/
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Jul  9 13:00 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 17 Jul  9 13:00 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Jul  9 13:00 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Jul  9 13:00 hwC0D3
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 16 Jul  9 13:00 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 15 Jul  9 13:00 hwC1D1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 14 Jul  9 13:00 hwC1D2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 Jul  9 13:00 hwC1D3
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Jul  9 13:00 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Jul 10 09:13 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jul  9 13:00 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jul  9 13:00 timer
```

getfacl run in x:

```
% getfacl /dev/snd/controlC0 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/snd/controlC0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

getfacl run in virtual terminal:

```
# file: dev/snd/controlC0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:jake:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Which audio output are you using? What are the permissions on the device nodes in `/dev/snd/`?

Comment: That plus sign means there is an ACL on those devices... So please add `getfacl` output from one of them. Also, are you member of the `audio` group?

Comment: @djeikyb Is that getfacl output when running X or not? Odd that there is nothing other than the standard permissions in that ACL.

Comment: @derobert whoa, i was a minute late on checking the difference in x vs vt. So it looks like the acl config(??) for sound is discriminatory. This is my first experience with acl and linux, I'm used to ye olde `chown` and `chmod`.